# How to get laravel records created between time range taking timezone into account

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel application where I sample data every hour and store it in the database.

Now I want to retrieve all records that are created at around 12:00 Europe/Amsterdam timezone. (This timezone has daylight savings)

So for example if I have records with the following created_at

- 2023-10-28 08:59:00
- 2023-10-28 10:01:00
- 2023-10-28 11:01:00
- 2023-10-28 11:59:00
- 2023-10-28 13:01:00
- ...
- 2023-10-29 09:01:00
- 2023-10-29 10:01:00
- 2023-10-29 10:59:00
- 2023-10-29 12:00:00
- 2023-10-29 13:01:00
- ...
- 2023-10-30 09:00:00
- 2023-10-30 10:01:00
- 2023-10-30 11:00:00
- 2023-10-30 12:01:00
- 2023-10-30 13:00:00

I would like to retrieve the records where created_at is:

- 2023-10-28 11:01:00
- 2023-10-29 10:01:00
- 2023-10-30 10:01:00

Can anyone help me with how I would create an Eloquent query for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code snippet, `CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+00:00','+01:00')` is used to convert the `created_at` timestamp from UTC to the Europe/Amsterdam timezone. The `TIME` function extracts the time portion from the timestamp. The `whereRaw` method is subsequently used to filter the records, selecting only those where the time falls between 11:00:00 and 12:00:00.

```
$records = DB::table('your_table')
    ->whereRaw("TIME(CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+00:00','+01:00')) >= ?", ['11:00:00'])
    ->whereRaw("TIME(CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'+00:00','+01:00')) <= ?", ['12:00:00'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: this one will always do full table scan, no?

Comment: This helps. However the second parameter of CONVERT_TZ 'to_tz' is not +01:00 when daylightssavings are active. So for a date in winter it should be +1 and for a date in winter it should be +2.

Comment: I meant for summer it should be +2

Comment: CONVERT_TZ(date_time,'UTC','Europe/Amsterdam') is possible, but for this to work you need to setup the timezone tables in your database. See https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/populating-mysql-mariadb-timezone-tables